# IE MP3 Streaming. Works fine in Firefox but not in IE and Chrome. Header problems

Tags: php, javascript, flash

I have a bit of a problem with streaming MP3s in IE and Chrome (it works fine in Firefox)

We have a voicemail server. The web app streams the wav file by converting it on the fly to MP3 (using lame, not great, but we have to do it is this way because of limitations of asterisk) and then outputs the content as a binary stream.

```
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");    
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');    
$file->readFromInbox($f);
```

The MP3 audio player we're using is: http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone/

If the file is (I think) less than 100k in size, the audio streams fine and the MP3 flash audio player status bar is updated(the seconds go up, and the bar moves along).

However, if the file is bigger than 100k then there is a problem. The audio plays in IE7/8 and Chrome but the status bar doesn't change. It continues to say 'Connecting...' even though the audio is being played. Odd.

In Firefox, I have no problems.

What could be the problem? Why does firefox not have any problems but IE and Chrome? Do I need to specify the size of the file being streamed? (Which isn't possible as the file is being converted on the fly and being outputted straight away because of the passthru command)

Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you sending a Content-Length header?

Comment: It's not possible to add a content length header....because I don't know the length of the file. it's being converted on the fly and outputted straight away

Comment: Is the file getting converted first and then sent? or is it being sent as its getting converted?

Comment: correct. passthru("/usr/bin/lame -h --quiet '$file' -"). If i could pass that passthru output into a variable, it would be better, alas, that's not possible. The "-" at the end of the lame command means to output the binary to stdout....

Comment: You could store the output to a temp file and then send that. I think your problems are being caused by the lack of the Content-Length header.

Comment: @datasage - You are correct. :-) Thank you good sir! If you put it down as an answer, i'll accept it as the right answer :-) I changed the code to:  '    $tmpFile = "/tmp/" . sha1(microtime(true).mt_rand(10000,90000));
    $command = "/usr/bin/lame -h --quiet '$file' $tmpFile";
    exec($command, $output, $return);
    $data = array("data"=>file_get_contents($tmpFile),
         "size"=>filesize($tmpFile));
    unlink($tmpFile);
    return $data; ' Obviously other checks are in place for checking if the file exists etc. works a treat! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the file first and store it as a tempfile. Then send that file along with the Content-Length header.

A temp file cam be created with this:

```
$tempfile = tempnam('/tmp','mp3')
```